# If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $A^2$ is also symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I first tried if the claim was true by testing it with a symmetric matrix, and I got that if I have a symmetric square matrix $A$ then $A^2$ is also symmetric.
So to prove this for a general case I did:

First of all I take a general square matrix

$$A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   a_{11} & a_{12} & ...a_{1n}\\
   a_{21} & a_{12} & ...a_{1n}\\
   ... & ... & ...\\
   a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ...a_{nn}\\
  \end{array} } \right]$$
we can see that the matrix above is symmetric because it is equal to its transpose.

Then I calculate
$$A^2=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{1k}a_{k1} & \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{1k}a_{k2} & ...\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{1k}a_{kn}\\
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k}a_{k1} & \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k}a_{k2} & ...\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k}a_{kn}\\
   ... & ... & ...\\
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{nk}a_{k1} & \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{nk}a_{k2} & ...\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{nk}a_{kn}\\
  \end{array} } \right]$$
so I get that $A^2$ is symmetric because it is equal to its transpose $(A^2)^T$ or we can say that because $a_{ij}a_{ji}=a_{ji}a_{ij}$ for all $1\le i,j\le n$.

Do you think this is a good proof or how can I improve it? Thanks

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then $A^t=A$. Since $(A^t)^2=A^2$, $A^2$ is also symmetric. Use induction to prove that if $A$ symmetric, then $A^n$ is also symmetric.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not directly?: We're given $\;A\;$ is symmetric $\;\iff A^t=A\;$ , and then

$$(A^2)^t=(AA)^t=A^tA^t=AA=A^2\implies A^2\;\;\text{is symmetric}$$

Or in short: $\;(A^2)^t=(A^t)^2=A^2\;$

Comment: Wow this is a much more nicer answer than mine, but do you think that mine also make sense?

Comment: @Alcakram Yes, it looks fine though I didn't check little details. So many sums makes that hard to read...but it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Note that this requires you to prove something like $(AB)^t = B^tA^t$; which is a good thing to know anyway, but I'm pretty sure the easiest proof comes down to something like what the questioner already wrote.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Of course, yet that is one of the first things taught/shown when dealing with transposes.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let's prove to $A^n$ instead of $A^2$

Let's prove using induction on $n$ that $A=A^t \implies A^n = (A^n)^t$

Base case is $n=1$, that is $A = A^t$, that is true by hypothesis.

Assuming that is true for $n = k$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $A^k = (A^k)^t$ , this is our inductive hypothesis.

We need prove it for $n=k+1$, that is, $A^{k+1}=(A^{k+1})^t$

And this is trivial to prove, since $A^{k+1}=A^k \cdot A=(A^k)^t \cdot A^t = (A^t)^k\cdot (A^t)= (A^t)^{k+1}=(A^{k+1})^t$

$$\Box$$

So our conclusion is that if $A$ is a symmetric matrix therefore $A^n$ is also symmetric.